# Event Not working with Guest user

Tags: magento2

```
 <event name="sales_order_invoice_save_commit_after">
    <observer name="abc_syncInvoice" 
       instance="abc\def\Observer\Invoice\Create"/>
 </event>
```

I have created this event,

For this event when I place an order with the existing customer but not work without login guest customer why this happened any idea.

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    if ($this->isConnected() && $this->isConnected() == 1) {
        try {
            /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice $invoice */
            $invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
            $note = $invoice->getCustomerNote();
            if ($note != 'quickbook') {
                $incrementId = $invoice->getIncrementId();
                if ($incrementId && $this->isEnabled()) {
                    if ($this->isImmediatelyMode()) {
                        $qboId = $this->_invoice->sync($incrementId);
                        if($qboId)
                            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('Successfully updated this Invoice(Id: %1) in QuickBooksOnline.', $qboId));
                    } else {
                        $this->addToQueue($incrementId);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This event should work but i guess you have an issue at `abc\def\Observer\Invoice\Create`

Comment: yes but no log creating in this observer

Comment: Share your observer code

Comment: check my updated question